# cakephp app as part of static site

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have kind of an unique situation. 
I have developed a cakephp app and need to deploy it to a shared server with content.
I know generally we are supposed to have static content in webroot, but am not allowed to do so, as this application needs to be removed later on.

its a shared hosting and i can't change DocumentRoot or any admin related settings. I can however add .htacces files.

I have my files in the following order:

```
    /webapp
       /app
       /lib
       ...
       /webroot
```

I guess you get the point.
I was planning to deploy the entire 'webapp' folder along with the static site and have the login link so the people can come to the site as http://mysite.com/webapp/users/login.
Unfortunately I do not know the correct way to do this. I hope to preserve the directory structure as-is so that someone coming after me can easily modify and delete it.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
I forgot to mention that locally i used to access the site by

```
http://localhost/webapp
```

, which was based of a DocumentRoot/VirtualHost setting. I might not be able to do that on prod, so how can I translate that using routes?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. You description seems to cover it.  What is not working?

Comment: i am looking for setting changes to make in .htaccess, index.php and other similar files like core.php etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `.htaccess` files to reference `/webapp/app/webroot/` instead of `/app/webroot/`.

Although I’d be tempted to just install the CakePHP app in the root of your web server’s publicly-accessible directory, use CakePHP’s built-in `PagesController` to serve the static files, and just remove the controllers as and when you need to.

Comment: unfortunately i can't use the standard you mentioned for static files...this is just a temp app and i'll be leaving soon...its easier to write instructions to remove a folder than re-configure things up.

Comment: also, i did add the .htaccess settings like: /webapp/.htaccess => ReweriteBase /webapp   | /webapp/app/.htaccess => Rewritebase /webapp/app/    and /webapp/app/webroot/.htaccess => Rewritebase /webapp/app/webroot/   and this seems to work...i can't vouch 100% as there seems to be a missing PDO mysql driver and i can verify after that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serve CakePHP from a subdirectory using Apache, you're looking for the [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive. Add the directive to each of your three `.htaccess` files (in CakePHP root, in `app`, and in `app/webroot`). For example, the root one will end up looking like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteBase    /webapp
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now Cake will be happy being served in your `webapp` subdirectory.

Comment: thank you for the reply. so i need to add "RewriteBase /webapp" in all 3.htaccess files or is it different for each?

Comment: I added the /webapp and i had the routes configured in my dev machine that when i do http://localhost/webapp it should route to http://localhost/webapp/users/login .. but somehow in the prod site, cake is looking for WebappController ... now i used DocumentRoot in my local app, how do i translate that over?

Comment: The .htaccess files themselves change but the RewriteBase directive is the same in each